# Is it possible to avoid '/authorize' sufifx using @auth0/auth0-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, auth0

In our project we are using Authorization Code Flow with PKCE and we have custom domain for OAuth2 authentication server.

On FE side @auth0/auth0-react library is used. The problem is that 'loginWithRedirect' method (and other login* methods) append '/authorize' suffix to specified domain. In this case the call should be directed to URL ending with '/as/authorization.oauth2'. Is it possible to overwrite this default behaviour?